# Can we get short formula to get the curl of a function $ M \hat{i} + N \hat{j} +O \hat{k} $

Tags: vector-fields

Can we get short formula to get the curl of a function $$M \hat{i} + N \hat{j} +O \hat{k} $$. For $$M \hat{i} + N \hat{j}$$ we know $\partial N /\partial x - \partial M/\partial y $ would give the curl.  But do we have something for 3 dimensional vector fields also ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 3D, 
$$\text{curl } \hat{F} = \nabla \times \hat{F} 
= 
\det
\begin{bmatrix}
\hat{i} &  \hat{j} & \hat{k} \\
\frac{\partial }{\partial x} &  \frac{\partial }{\partial y} & \frac{\partial }{\partial z} \\
M & N & O
\end{bmatrix}$$
where $$\hat{F} = M \hat{i} + N \hat{j} + O \hat{k}$$